# Django middleware process_view get view class?

Tags: django, middleware

I am using classed based views and I want to create a middleware to redirect to other places under some conditions.

I have tried using `process_request()` but I will need to add exclusions to avoid loops.

What I am experimenting is to exclude views of a base view class, but `process_view()` gets view function, see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view), it seems like I cannot get the view class from it, I am asking here to verify if that's true or there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is indeed no way to get the actual view class. However, you can override the `as_view` method as follows:

```
class ViewClassMixin(object):
    @class_method
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super(ViewClassMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        view.cls = cls
        return view
```

Credits go to the django-rest-framework who use this method in their [view classes](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L132).

Then the view class is accessible as the `cls` attribute on the actual view function.

**Update:** 1.9 will add the same behaviour to Django's own class-based views. The view function returned by `View.as_view()` will have a `view_class` attribute.

Comment: that's what I had as well, I am changing it to become a decorator like `login_required`

Answer (score 1):

A bit out of scope of my question:

Instead of excluding views of a base view class, I have opted for a decorator style like `login_required`

```
def skip_user_status_sync(view_func):
    """ marks the view function to skip sync middleware """
    view_func.skip_user_status_sync = True
    return view_func
```

in urls, like `login_required`:

```
url(r'^logout/$', skip_user_status_sync(views.Logout.as_view()), name='logout'),
```

then in middleware to inspect that function attribute:

```
class UserStatusSyncMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        if hasattr(view_func, 'skip_user_status_sync'):
            return None
```